# Going down on a site with "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server"

Tags: php, memory, connection

I've a site that constantly goes down with the message below.

> #### Unable to connect
>
> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at
>
> - The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
> - If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
> - If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

What are the possible reasons that's causing this message to be shown?

The hosting is saying the script is taking too much memory. Is this really the case?

Comment: There are many possibilities for this, although a PHP script shouldn't usually die this badly when hitting the memory limit. Hard to tell without more info

Comment: Maybe there's too many people trying to access your website?

Comment: If you have an infinite loop, this can cause PHP / memory limit issues and after a couple refreshes of the script, it may not throw the "exhausted" error, since it is eating up the server memory / cpu it just throws the unable to connect.

Comment: Do you have access to the server's error logs? That would have more details.

Comment: the traffic is not that huge.  if theres an infinite loop, shouldn't the site be down every single moment?  but its down randomly. not everyday.  kinda lost as to where to start the troubleshooting

Comment: How much memory is your script using? (You can use `ps aux` or `top` commands if your hosting environment provides you with these tools.) You might be hitting [php internal limits](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) or [`setrlimit` OS-enforced limits](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) or maybe your hosting provider only gave you a VPS with a certain amount of memory, and your server+PHP require more than their memory+swap supports. I suggest asking them for further details, they are there to help you. :)

Comment: I wonder if this should be on serverfault?

Comment: does it only happen to you? or are others experiencing the same issue? it might be a local connection problem rather than something with the host.

Answer (score 1):

To start troubleshooting replace your index.php (being sure to keep a copy of the original) with something as basic as `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and see if that works consistently.

If it does (assuming it is something in your index.php) you can start working through your original index.php adding a bare-bones framework to start with and add more code until eventually it breaks.

Troubleshooting is easy if you start from one end or the other and work towards the "trouble".  In this case, start with minimal code, keep adding until something goes wrong.